# Content around featured image

Tags: images, editor, text

any ideas how I can make this way:
: http://f.cl.ly/items/41332V031Z1G2h0j0B33/example.jpg

I have product image as featured image now. And I want to move text what is written in editor next to it. I am also using tabs plugin and need it to stay 100% of content width under the image. tabs come from short code in editor.

Excerpt is in use as preview text with thumbnails in archive.php. Otherwise maybe I could have made first text as excerpt and short code in editor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't present the code you are currently using, it's difficult to answer. But you could consider adding `float: right;` to the CSS of the featured image?